# only first product image appears in woocommerce and rest doesn't works

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, flexslider

i am using my website with woocommerce but the problem is when i click on product and lands to product page and check the first image its works fine and zoom perfectly on mouse hover, but when i click on the 2nd one nothing appears, and then if i go to the first one its zoom started creating issue and doesnt work smoothly..

I tried every possible way by changing size etc but it doesn't works even if i upload the same image on main thumbnail(above in product page) and gallery(below in product page)..still it works same and creates issue on 2nd one

also tried upload new plugin nothing works..please help..attaching some image

[image]

Comment: do you get a console error?

Comment: @gael no..no error in console